# am trying to calculate GPA using stored function in MySQL. GPA = SUM(gradePoint * credit)/ SUM(credit). I endup getting syntanx problem

Tags: mysql

this is what i performed in the terminal.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION calculateGPA( sReg varchar (30), semista int, acYear varchar(30))
RETURNS decimal
NOT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
   
    
    DECLARE creditPoint int;
    
    DECLARE gpa decimal(2,1);

    DECLARE scorePoint decimal(3,1);

    DECLARE gradePoint int default 0;
    
    DECLARE loopIndex int default 0;
    
    DECLARE jumla int;
    select count(*) into jumla from student;
    
    WHILE loopIndex < jumla DO
    
    select score, credit into scorePoint, creditPoint from enrollment inner join modules on enrollment.moduleCode = modules.moduleCode limit loopIndex,1;
    if scorePoint < 30 then set gradePoint = gradePoint + 0;
    elseif scorePoint < 40 then set gradePoint = gradePoint + 1;
    elseif scorePoint < 50 then set gradePoint = gradePoint + 2;
    elseif scorePoint < 60 then set gradePoint = gradePoint + 3;
    elseif scorePoint < 70 then set gradePoint = gradePoint + 4;
    else scorePoint < 100 then set gradePoint = gradePoint + 5;
    
    end if;
    
    set gpa = sum(gradePoint * credit)/sum(credit);
    
    set loopIndex = loopIndex + 1;
    where studentID = sReg AND semester = semista AND aYear = acYear;

    
END WHILE;
return(gpa);
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Please provide some more debugging details, such as errors you get. The question as is is a little unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Else has no condition and you have a abandoned where clause, which i put into the select

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION calculateGPA( sReg varchar (30), semista int, acYear varchar(30))
RETURNS decimal
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
   
    
    DECLARE creditPoint int;    
    DECLARE gpa decimal(2,1);
    DECLARE scorePoint decimal(3,1);
    DECLARE gradePoint int default 0;
    DECLARE loopIndex int default 0;    
    DECLARE jumla int;
    select count(*) into jumla from student;
    
    WHILE loopIndex < jumla DO
    
        select score, credit into scorePoint, creditPoint 
        from enrollment inner join modules on enrollment.moduleCode = modules.moduleCode 
        where studentID = sReg AND semester = semista AND aYear = acYear
        limit loopIndex,1;
        if scorePoint < 30 then set gradePoint = gradePoint + 0;
        elseif scorePoint < 40 then set gradePoint = gradePoint + 1;
        elseif scorePoint < 50 then set gradePoint = gradePoint + 2;
        elseif scorePoint < 60 then set gradePoint = gradePoint + 3;
        elseif scorePoint < 70 then set gradePoint = gradePoint + 4;
        else 
         set gradePoint = gradePoint + 5;       
        end if;    
        set gpa = sum(gradePoint * credit)/sum(credit);    
        set loopIndex = loopIndex + 1;
    
    END WHILE;
return(gpa);
END//
DELIMITER ;
```